# IIS w3wp process hanging og blocking access to the website

Tags: iis

Every night my IIS hangs with 3 w3wp.exe processen in the task manager list. It is not possible to kill the w3wp task using the most memory. Not even iisreset helps. I have to reboot the machince to get rid of the w3wp prosess.

Any suggestions?

[image: http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/7417/taskmanagerw3wpjn4.jpg]

Added: I have reduced the maxmemory of the default app pool to 120, but still the process goes above 200mb.

Answer (score 0):

In the app-pool, set a limit on memory use, that will restart the app. when it uses too much memory. Might help.

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shot, I cannot see problems such as high CPU utilization or huge memory usage.

You can learn how to use Debug Diagnostics to capture a hang dump and then analyse the dump with Debug Diagnostics. Its report should provide you some hints.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en

If you cannot do that yourself, I suggest you contact our Microsoft Support team.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a permament solution to my problem, but when i removed some web sites from my vps and reduced the max memory allowed for the default app pool the situation improved. I also removed the admin website which ran under its own appPool.